# Customization background dialog at press KEYCODE_MENUBUTTON

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, keydown, keyevent, keycode

actually when I press the Keycode_menu_button will appear a dialog with a grey background and white text. So, how I can for change background color and text of the dialog?

Comment: Show the codes what you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

`@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
            Log.d("Ok", "premuto");
            Toast.makeText(this,"Premuto",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            //return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }'

if not comment return super.onKeydown..a dialog appears, and I will customize background colour of that dialog.